# How to add a imported library target for a shared library without soname inside project dir in cmake under Linux?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, shared-libraries, ld

Suppose there's a shared library file called `foo.so` in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`, which is created without soname specified. (In this case I created this library file by writing a simple C source file `foo.c` and then build it with `g++ -shared -o foo.so -std=c++17 -O2 -fPIC foo.c`)

Also there's an executable target called `bar` in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt` that wants to link with this shared library. It also has its `install` command written as follows:

```
install(TARGETS bar
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
```

I am going to build this project under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build` and installed it in somewhere outside `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`. My question is, how should I create the imported library called `foo` so that after I call `target_link_libraries(bar foo)` and install the whole project, the generated executable for target `bar` would correctly find and link `foo.so`?

#### Approaches I've tried yet failed

1. Create target `foo` using the following code:

   ```
   add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
   set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.so)
   ```

   - Though it would work if I build the project out of `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`, CMake would convert path of `foo.so` to path relative to build directory if I put build directory inside `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`. When I tried to invoke executable `bar`, GNU ld would report that `../foo.so`(or similar) cannot be found.
2. Create target `foo` using the following code:

   ```
   add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
   set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.so IMPORTED_NO_SONAME ON)
   ```

   - This would cause cmake to link `foo.so` with arguments like `-lfoo`, which in turn requires the shared library name be `libfoo.so` instead of `foo.so`, causing build failure.
3. Create target foo using the following code:

   ```
   add_library(foo SHARED IMPORTED)
   set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.so IMPORTED_SONAME "foo.so")
   ```

   - The result is exactly the same with 1, and I cannot observe any differences during build and install process.

I am facing this problem under Linux and I'm using GCC/G++ 11.0, GNU ld 2.36.1, GNU libc 2.33 and CMake 3.21.3, but of course, solutions for any other versions (if any) would be welcomed too.

Comment: `When I tried to invoke executable bar, GNU ld would report that ../foo.so(or similar) cannot be found.` If you want to _install_ a library so it is found by `ld.so`, copy it to `/usr/lib` or use `LD_PRELOAD` or modify `/etc/ld.so.conf` and add additional paths for `ld.so`. Compiling with a library != running with a library, `ld.so` != `ld`. Cmake is for compiling stuff. If you want to hardcode the path, then research RPATH.

Comment: I am currently running into the same problem, so I can clarify this hopefully: as long as your imported library follows the `lib*.so` naming convention you can just set the `IMPORTED_SO_NAME` property and all is fine. However, for libraries _not_ following the convention this does not work: CMake seems to just strip the `.so` suffix from the library name when using it in the `-l` parameter, thus making the build fail. The desired behavior in the given example would be that the created executable just links against `foo.so` (without any prepended path).

Comment: I should add that I already struggle to construct a linker command line that can achieve this. When I call the linker using `-l:foo.so` I end up having the relative path prepended in the dynamic section of the executable, just like in the presented approaches 1 and 3. Is there a way to prevent the addition of the path? In the `ld` call or event from within CMake? That would be the answer to the original question, I guess.